# Rename Week Attribute in Time Dimension SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

My time dimension in SSAS have an attribute of week number. How to rename the week name depending on if a week matches the current week at today's date. For instance this is week 18 in 2017, when retrieving the week name from Time Dimension I want it to be named Current Week.
Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

`DATEPART` can tell you the week of the current date.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.Test AS DATEPART("ww", now())
SELECT Measures.Test on columns
FROM TestCube
```

This returns you an integer which you can then compare to the Week # in your dimension.

Answer (score 0):

No, MDX doesn't provide you ability to change the caption of static member. However, you can set the name on the DWH level (the Date dimension reprocessing shouldn't last too long). Also, you can [create a dynamic member](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/the-dynamic-members.html), which is an extra member calculated on runtime, thus it won't replace the CurrentMember. Actually, you may force to return **week 18** as *NULL* value and **CurrentWeek** as *week 18* value, but bear in mind, it produces side effects, like ordering:

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Date].[Week].[CurrentWeek] as 
StrToMember('[Date].[Week].&[' + Cstr(Year(Now())) + Cstr(DatePart( "ww", Now())) + ']')), 
Visible = 1;  


Scope(StrToMember('[Date].[Week].&[' + Cstr(Year(Now())) + Cstr(DatePart( "ww", Now())) + ']'));           
        This = NULL;  
End Scope;
```

Comment: How to force to return CurrentWeek instead of week 18 ?